# What process for applying graphics to painted plastic or metal surfaces?

Tags: print-design, interface-design, print-production, screen-printing, overprint

I'm working on a project where I need to apply graphics to both painted plastic and metal surfaces that will be outdoors and have UV exposure.

These surfaces will experience moderate wear and tear throughout their lifetime so that should be considered.

Additionally, we need a process that's cost effective and can be applied relatively quickly since this'll be done at scale 100's of times per day.

I've looked into inkjet transfer process which seems promising, but I don't know the specifics of things like which inks to use, which transfer process, etc.

Are there any other methods you'd recommend?

Also - if this is the wrong site on stack exchange for this type of question, where should I post it? This seemed most appropriate

Comment: Are you looking for a solution you can produce yourself (at scale 100s of times per day)? or outsource - what are the surfaces types, merchandise?

Comment: Hey! I'm looking for something that I can produce myself.

Comment: The surface is a plastic that's pre-infused with red color. (red plastic) I'm not sure what the material is, the plastic's circular in nature

Comment: I think you may find it hard to do this on your own on home equipment as the ink has to be dense enough to cover the red - this would normally be done by 'screen printing' or 'padding' which allows the ink to be transferred onto the surface. Not sure about the UV resistance of your home printer either - you could look into vinyl stickers... such as these https://www.stickermule.com/au/custom-stickers

Comment: The most important factor we need to know is whether your graphics are full-color or spot color. Also explain what type of wear the surface will be subject to. Will it be sat on, walked on, etc. What is your expected budget?